# Top like pictures - mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a celebrity pictures website, so in this site users can like this pictures.

I want to show 10 most liked pictures of today!

table posts:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `foto` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

foto is the picture URL and data that I post this picture.

and likes:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `likes` (
  `ip` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `post` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (`post`) REFERENCES posts (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

ip is the user who likes the picture and post is the ID of Posts table.

I want to get the today most likes posts. Is it possible? So far I have tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(likes) AS rank FROM likes
```

Comment: Yes it is. What have you tried?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(likes) AS rank FROM likes and I have no idea what to do next (and even if it is right)

Comment: You need to join with post table and count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a `dt` column (data type should be date or datetime) in `likes` table and save the time when the photo is liked in this column, then use this query to get today likes

```
SELECT p.id, count(*) as cnt
FROM posts p INNER JOIN likes l ON p.id=l.post
WHERE date(l.dt) = current_date()
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

This query will return today's like count of each post as `cnt` along with its `id`. Sorted as post with most likes at top

Comment: oh, it is nice! can't I use the POSTS datatime row in this case? or it is not a good idea?

Comment: No, using posts date will not achieve what you desire

Answer (score 0):

You should write a [`SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) query that [JOINs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) two tables together using posts.id and likes.post columns. You may use [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html) to ensure that each pic is only shown once and [COUNT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) is the key to checking how many likes there, are per picture. [`ORDER BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) helps you to find the highest ranking pictures while `WHERE`limits your scope to specific date or date. Use `LIMIT` restrict the result set size.